# Why does Brisk start programs without some of my user's permissions?

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-mate, appmenu

I'm having a bit of trouble with the Brisk menu.
When I start a terminal program(I use cutecom) from the menu and try to open a serial port, it says I do not have the required permissions to do so.
This is wrong, because I've added my user to the dialout group, and when I start it from a .desktop file or from the terminal it works just fine.
Something about how Brisk starts things seems to be at fault regarding permissions.

What's causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Consider to ask on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .